# How do properties of a partial order $\mathbb{P}$ affect the logic of the functor category $\mathsf{Set}^\mathbb{P}$?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

$\DeclareMathOperator\true{\mathsf{true}}$I am very suspicious the answer to this (family of) question(s) is well-known, but I couldn't find anything after a bit of searching so I'll ask anyway.

I am interested in how the logic associated with the algebra of subobjects in the functor category $\mathsf{Set}^\mathbb{P}$ (for a partial order $\mathbb{P}$) varies with different properties of $\mathbb{P}$. Thus far, all I've been able to find is:

Fact 1. $\mathbb{P}$ is (weakly) linearly-ordered iff the logic of the topos is intuitionistic logic with the classical tautology $(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \vee (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$ added (so called Dummett's logic).

Fact 2. If $\mathbb{P}$ has a least element then the topos is disjunctive (i.e. if $y : 1 \to \Omega$ and $z: 1 \to \Omega$ are truth-values, then $y \cup z = \true$ iff $y = \true$ or $z= \true$). I *think* this implication can be reversed, but I'm not sure.

I was wondering if anything more is known about how the logic of the topos varies according to the properties of $\mathbb{P}$ (and vice versa)? I'd be interested in any information here, but to make things more concrete, is it known:

Q1. If the logic is affected when $\mathbb{P}$ is directed or has incompatible elements?

Q2. If $\mathbb{P}$ has incompatible elements, does the size of the largest antichain matter?

Q3. What if $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't have a least element? (In particular can Fact 2's implication be reversed?)

Q4. $\mathbb{P}$ has (or doesn't have) a maximal element?

(An aside: In the presentation I'm most familiar with (namely Goldblatt's [book](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486450260.html)) there is a restriction that $\mathbb{P}$ be a small category. I don't know whether this is essential for the results, or just made for metamathematical ease/queasiness.)

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: If $P$ isn't small then functor categories out of it generally fail to be locally small (an easy example is if $P$ is a discrete proper class). The category $[P^{op}, \text{Set}]$ of presheaves on $P$ also generally fails to be the free cocompletion of $P$ (which is one of its more useful properties when $P$ is small); for that you want to restrict to the "small" presheaves (the ones which are a small colimit of representables).

Comment: Even with the restriction to small presheaves, the lack of a small generating set means some things no longer exist (= are representable as smal presheaves) “for free”. For example, subobject classifiers and exponential.

Comment: What's $\bf Set^{\Bbb P}$? Is it the $\Bbb P$-names? Or just functions from $\Bbb P$ to $\bf Set$? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category

Comment: @Gabe: Sure, but *what does it even mean*? (For someone like me, that is, a Regular, Normal, Joe Hausdorff.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess the objects of the category are commuting systems $\langle X_p,f_{pq} : p\in \mathbb P\rangle$  of sets  $X_p$ and functions $f_{pq} : X_p\to X_q$ and an arrow from $\langle X_p,f_{pq} : p\in \mathbb P\rangle$ to $\langle Y_p,g_{pq} : p\in \mathbb P\rangle$ is a sequence $\langle h_p : p\in \mathbb P\rangle$ of functions $h_p : X_p\to Y_p$ such that all the diagrams commute, i.e., $h_q\circ f_{pq} = g_{pq}\circ h_p$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. @ZhenLin, if I'm willing to pay a metamathematical price then I assume the problem disappears? For example, let's interpret $Set$ as the sets of some countable transitive model $M \models ZFC$. Let's let $\mathbb{P} = Ord(M)$. Then a functor in $Set^\mathbb{P}$ isn't going to be an object in $M$, nor is a natural transformation. But presumably I can talk about anything in $Set^\mathbb{P}$ using sets outside (e.g. the functors and natural transformations are going to proper classes of M, but can be treated as objects in $\mathcal{P}(M)$.)

Comment: One more instance for your list:  the topos satisfies the weak excluded middle $\neg\varphi\lor\neg\neg\varphi$ if $P$ is *confluent*, i. e. for all $x\leqslant y,y'$ there exists $z$ with $y,y'\leqslant z$ (in particular if $P$ is directed).

Comment: If you interpret "internal logic" in a strict sense, then the answer to Q3 is no. The internal logic only detect local properties, and $Set^P$ is locally $Set^{p \downarrow P}$ and $p \downarrow P$ has a lest element.

Comment: @SimonHenry is right about the internal logic.  But externally when you mean logic of the truth values, which are subobjects of 1, or equivalently global elements of $\Omega$, as you do in stating Fact 2, then the answer to Q3 is yes, and worth verifying.

Comment: @NeilBarton You can do that, yes, but the resulting category is not an elementary topos. For instance, if you don’t restrict the functors somehow then you will have too many subobjects to have a subobject classifier. I think exponentials are also problematic.

Comment: You know Dieudonne and Grothendieck used their "universes" to avoid worrying about smallness--in any fixed sense of small--while keeping a simple, well understood metatheory.

Comment: @Neil Barton There was several messages by people as P. Johnston, S. Vickers and O. Caramello on category theory mailing list in concern to this question. I guess it worth to make their suggestions here, if some of them answer the question. So that other people can see possible references too.

Comment: Great idea Evgeny! I need to read and digest some of the material presented. I'll edit the question with some of these inputs over the next week or so, and hopefully type up a proper answer in the next couple of months.